# Saving Core Data to external backup file

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I have a travel planner app I’m working on that uses Core Data for data storage. Two of my many entities (Person and Trip) have a many-to-many relationship (one person may go on many trips, and a single trip includes many people). I would like to add a feature that gives the user the opportunity to create an external backup file of their data as a txt file that can either live in iCloud, or a location in Files. I will need to be able to serialize and deserialize for backup and restore operations.

From what I’ve read it seems that JSON can only do one-to-many relationships (strictly hierarchical), not many-to-many. If I’m mistaken and it can indeed do many-to-many, can someone help me understand how to serialize that?

But if in fact it cannot, what other methods would be recommended for backing up Core Data into a txt file? Ideally this would be something that Swift has native methods for serializing and deserializing.

Comment: I have found that when dealing with CoreData and JSON you have to pick a direction Parent > Child. It is more complicated than it’s worth to setup Codable + CoreData in both directions. It is a point of weakness since ideally you should be able to do both.

Comment: I agree with the above and also note if you think of it as one direction then you only need a one-to-many relationship in your json as long as you always encode and decode in the same direction. So for instance encode trips as having many persons and when decoding set the person for a trip and Core Data will handle the inverse for you.

Comment: I use also the parent > child and Codeable + CoreData. You ma also normalize your model to eliminate the many-to-many relation by a table with the primary keys of both entities, to eliminate the many to many relationship. as  Person <-> PersonID,TripID <-> Trip. So you can serialize the tables...

Comment: @Joakim I wasn't aware that Core Data would automatically handle the inverse relationship when decoding. I thought I had to be explicit about that. I'll give this method a go and see what I learn.

Comment: AFAIK, `CoreData` is a layer on top of `SQLite`, so it should be possible to use `SQLite` to backup all your 
 entities and their relationships, that can either live in iCloud, or a location in Files. Note, that `SQLite` is included with iOS.

Comment: In your CoreData code, you could just use:
 `let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataTest")` and then copy the resulting
 sqlite db file wherever you like. Somewhere like:
 "/Users/username.../Library/Containers/bundle id..../Data/Library/Application%20Support/CoreDataTest/CoreDataTest.sqlite"

Comment: Usually when doing this kind of export, you don't set the "relations" directly in the "JSON" (or XML, or other format), you put an "id" (or array of id), allowing you to have relations in multiple ways. Example: `{"persons":  [ {"id": "personId",  "trips": [tripId1, tripId2, etc.] } ...}` &   "{trips: [{"id": tripId1, "persons": [personId1, personId2, etc.]}]}`etc, and you redo yourself the relations in your DataBase if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have something like that:

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: UUID
    @NSManaged var trips: Set<Trip>
}

class Trip: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: UUID
    @NSManaged var persons: Set<Person>
}
```

One way to share that (to a third party lib, a server, or in your case a copy), could be to transforms the "many-to-many" into arrays of UUIDs. That way, the other party just have to "redo" the connection if needed.

If we think in JSON (but it could be XML, or any other format), one way would be, in "one big file mode"

```
{
    "persons": [
                    { "id": "personId1", "trips": ["tripId1", 
                                                   "tripId2", 
                                                   "tripId3"]
                    },
                    { "id": "personId2", "trips": ["tripId3", 
                                                   "tripId5"]
                    },
                ],
    "trips": [ 
                 {"id": "tripId1", "persons": ["personId1"]},
                 {"id": "tripId2", "persons": ["personId1"]},
                 {"id": "tripId3", "persons": ["personId1", "personId2"]},
                 {"id": "tripId4", "persons": []},
                 {"id": "tripId5", "persons": ["personId2"]},
             ]
}
```

You can now create an export method:

```
extension Person {
    func export() -> [String: Any] {
        ["id": id.uuidString,
         "trips": trips.map { $0.id.uuidString }]
    }
}

extension Trip {
    func export() -> [String: Any] {
        ["id": id.uuidString,
         "persons": persons.map { $0.id.uuidString }]
    }
}
```

You could also iterate on each properties to have something more "generic":

```
extension Person {
    func exportAttributes() -> [String: Any] {
        //might need a `context.perform()` here, it depends who calls it, from where, could be async method, or a with a completion, it's up to your own code
        entity.attributesByName.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) { $0[$1.key] = value(forKey: $1.key) }
    }
    
        //Sample with computing some values
    func exportAttributesWithExtraWork() -> [String: Any] {
                entity.attributesByName.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) {
            var finalKey = $1.key
            switch finalKey {
            case #keyPath(Person.id):
                finalKey = "personId" //Here, we want to have another key
            default:
                break
            }
            
            switch $1.value.attributeType {
            case .dateAttributeType:
                guard let date = value(forKey: $1.key) as? Date else { return }
                $0[finalKey] = date.timeIntervalSince1970 //It's just to show a sample where you change the value according to its type
            default:
                $0[finalKey] = value(forKey: $1.key)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Sample for relations
    func exportRelations() -> [String: Any] {
        entity.relationshipsByName.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) {
            if let trips = value(forKey: $1.key) as? Set<Trips> {
                $0[$1.key] = trips.map { aTrip in aTrip.id.uuidString }
            }
        }
    }

    func fullExport() -> [String: Any] {
        var dictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
        let attributes = exportAttributes()
        dictionary.merge(attributes, uniquingKeysWith: { (_, new)  in return new })
        let relations = exportRelations()
        dictionary.merge(relations, uniquingKeysWith: { (_, new)  in return new })
        return dictionary 
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for my current purposes. It doesn't leave the JSON as human readable as I'd like (UUIDs don't help you see the connection very well unfortunately) but I can at least get my data out, and presumably (still have to write the other side of this) back in.